# When will we have bulk image uplaod for Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I am waiting for this a lot. I think I started to use D7 too soon.

Comment: It's probably better to ask this question on the Drupal forums.

Comment: Ask the maintainers of the core module in question. SO is not the place to ask this question.

Comment: Totally valid question many Drupal users share; totally wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at http://drupal.org/project/plupload which integrates the http://www.plupload.com/ widget. Might be what you need.